# How can I add emoji in text using emoji library for android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, emoji, androidx

I am using `androidx` library for my android project, How can I add **emoji** with text and show it in `main_activity` `layout`?

Please Help me. I can't understand how to implement **emoji** in my project with `androidx` library.

Comment: Check this library may be help you here are edittext with inbuilt emoji keyboard

https://github.com/vanniktech/Emoji

Comment: You can learn about `emoji compat lib` [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji-compat), this lib help android phones to show `emoji` even if the phone is not updated to view the latest emoji

Comment: Official sample app https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/tree/master/EmojiCompatKotlin

Answer (score 0):

I hope Help You

add implementation 'com.vanniktech:emoji-ios:0.6.0' to gradle.

Example in :

https://github.com/vanniktech/Emoji